# How to uninstall MariaDB and re-install MySQL? MySQL install turns into MariaDB install

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, openssl, mariadb

I recently upgraded my CentOS system via the desktop. Mistake!

I had MariaDB, phpMyAdmin working just fine before - but after the upgrade they stopped.

I frantically googled and tried to follow some [tutorials](http://centosforge.com/node/how-replace-mysql-mariadb-centos-6-including-mysql-uninstall-instructions-and-yum-install) about MariaDB MySQL reinstall until I came to this one:

I executed this command to remove all of MySQL:

```
yum remove mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-devel mysql*
```

and then tried to reinstall MySQL:

as below - it crashes with errors as follows:

```
*****************************************************************
[root@localhost ~]# yum install mysql-server mysql mysql-devel
*****************************************************************

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * extras: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirror.rmg.io
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql-server is obsoleted by MariaDB-server, trying to install MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 instead
Package mysql is obsoleted by MariaDB-server, trying to install MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 instead
Package mysql-devel is obsoleted by MariaDB-devel, trying to install MariaDB-devel-5.5.29-1.i686 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-devel.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-devel
---> Package MariaDB-server.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-compat for package: MariaDB-common
---> Package MariaDB-server.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-compat.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
---> Package MariaDB-server.i686 0:5.5.29-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 for package: MariaDB-server
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 from mariadb has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 is needed by package MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 (mariadb)
MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 from mariadb has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libssl.so.10 is needed by package MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 (mariadb)
Error: Missing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 is needed by package MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 (mariadb)
Error: Missing Dependency: libssl.so.10 is needed by package MariaDB-server-5.5.29-1.i686 (mariadb)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

[root@localhost ~]
```

---

If I now try to install libssl.10, I get asked to install glibc libraries. 2.17 and 2.7.
Other discussions have said to stay clear of them as this will explode my system. I tried download 2.17 and it's huge - took ages to unzip.

Could someone please help me to completely remove MariaDB and install MySQL - so that I don't get the above errors and pushed over to MariaDB when I run:

```
yum install mysql-server mysql mysql-devel
```

There are tons of material on how to install MariaDB - but none I found so far that plainly explains how to go backwards to MySQL.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep openssl`?

Comment: You know this is a total f** you to Fedora. I said install mysql-server, you installed maria-db.

Comment: same in case of cent os. . I said install mysql-server, you installed maria-db even after removing the reponsitory of maria db  from /etc/yum.repo.d/

Answer (score 9):

You still have the MariaDB yum repository on your system. As long as you do so, MariaDB will continue to replace MySQL.

To resolve the issue, remove the MariaDB repository. Do this by locating the file (it may be named something like `mariadb.repo`) in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory. Once you locate the file, you may remove it, or you may edit the file and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

Comment: thank you - that looks good, but unfortunately i can't test it as after much hassle and a system crash mariadb is now running.. but phpmyadmin is not, throwing up:

Warning: session_write_close() [function.session-write-close]: open(/tmp/sess_680f0e76afa349f57e05a29e97fe30efa81cace1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php on line 44

when i have saved and completed my work, i will try and folow your commands to remove mariadb and go back to mysql.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have mysql you need to add the mysql-community repo `sudo rpm -Uvh http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm` and then you can install MySQLl like you normally do.

Comment: How to uninstall first: yum erase mysql-community* - that will also delete the repo, so you can then do the above.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you need remove `dbconfig-mysql` and install `dbconfig-no-thanks`